# pypyodbc doesn't connect when isql does?

Tags: python, linux, unixodbc, db2-400, pypyodbc

pypyodbc has worked for me in the past, but for some reason it's not working. I have this defined in ~/.odbc.ini

```
[as400]                                                                            
Description             = IBM i Access ODBC Driver                                 
Driver                  = IBM i Access ODBC Driver                              
System                  = mysystem                                     
UserID                  = myuser                                                  
Password                = mypass                                              
Naming                  = 0                                                         
DefaultLibraries        = QGPL                                                  
Database                =                                                       
ConnectionType          = 0                                                     
CommitMode              = 2                                                     
ExtendedDynamic         = 1                                                     
DefaultPkgLibrary       = QGPL                                                  
DefaultPackage          = A/DEFAULT(IBM),2,0,1,0,512                               
AllowDataCompression    = 1                                                        
MaxFieldLength          = 32                                                       
BlockFetch              = 1                                                        
BlockSizeKB             = 128                                                      
ExtendedColInfo         = 0                                                        
LibraryView             = ENU                                                   
AllowUnsupportedChar    = 0                                                     
ForceTranslation        = 0                                                     
Trace                   = 0
```

And can connect just fine with `$ isql as400`.

However with the following program:

```
import pypyodbc

conn = pypyodbc.connect("Driver={as400};System=mysystem;Uid=myuser;Pwd=mypass;")
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dbtest.py", line 3, in <module>
    conn = pypyodbc.connect("Driver={as400};System=mysystem;Uid=myuser;Pwd=mypass;")
  File "/home/wwerner/.virtualenvs/devtools/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 2435, in __init__
    self.connect(connectString, autocommit, ansi, timeout, unicode_results, readonly)
  File "/home/wwerner/.virtualenvs/devtools/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 2484, in connect
    check_success(self, ret)
  File "/home/wwerner/.virtualenvs/devtools/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 988, in check_success
    ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, ODBC_obj.dbc_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)
  File "/home/wwerner/.virtualenvs/devtools/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 964, in ctrl_err
    raise Error(state,err_text)
pypyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified')
```

I tried looking in the pypyodbc source for some way to mirror the `isql -v` ability but `VERBOSE = True` wasn't it. I also found a bug that apparently it *used* to just send the first letter and thought maybe somehow I've got that issue, but I couldn't figure out where I'd find that.

How can I get this working again?

Comment: Perhaps this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5QEEQhpRbQ) may help you

Comment: Sadly, deleting my dataset had no effect

Answer (score 0):

Your Python script is failing because 'as400' is the name of the ODBC **DSN** you created, so you need to use `DSN=as400` instead of `Driver={as400}` in the connection string.

Comment: No luck - `'DSN=as400;System...'` gave the same error.